# kentico continuous integration failure

Tags: kentico

I am try to synch my Kentico 9 database using ContinuousIntegration.exe -r.

I'm getting the following error message:

"The application is not a web application, it cannot provide database installation wizard. Please install the database externally, and setup the connection string."

The app has been setup as a web application.

I've run this through PowerShell and at the Command Prompt (Admin) and always get the same error. I've followed the online procedure exactly. No joy.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you launching the utility from the bin folder of your web app? The error can occur when the application is unable to connect to the Kentico database. That can happen if it can't locate web.config (by default it looks for it in the parent folder) or if CMSConnectionString is missing or is wrong.

Comment: Does the site itself run on your machine? Or do you only have the code? As Rocky mentioned it's most likely a missing or wrong connection string.

Comment: Thanks @rocky, as it turns out I was running ContinuousIntegration.exe from the Lib folder and not the CMS -> bin folder. All fixed now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the ContinuousIntegration.exe utility from bin folder (not Lib).